# Forecasting with Multilayer Perceptron

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, forecasting, mlp

I need help on forecasting with an MLP neural network. I implemented the network with keras and i trained it with a scaled monthly_sunspots dataset:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(look_back,))
inner = Dense(64)(inputs)
inner = Activation("relu")(inner)
inner = Dense(32)(inputs)
inner = Activation("relu")(inner)
inner = Dense(16)(inputs)
inner = Activation("relu")(inner)
outputs = Dense(1)(inner)
outputs = Activation("linear")(outputs)
#outputs = ReLU(max_value=max_range)(outputs)
mlp_model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
mlp_opt  = Adam(lr=0.001)
mlp_model.compile(mlp_opt, loss="mean_squared_error")
mlp_history = mlp_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), shuffle=False, batch_size=1)
```

With this results:

`Train Score: 0.00 MSE (0.06 RMSE)
Test Score: 0.01 MSE (0.08 RMSE)`

Then i plotted the train_set and the test_set with good results:

[These are the train and test trends, and loss and val_loss trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Oil.png)

The problem is when i try to forecast with a new data. I created a function that computes sample from a seed with window method. This is the function:

```
def forward(model, seed_start, steps=3, lib="keras"):
  assert seed_start.shape[0] == 1, "Insert only one element"
  predictions = []
  series = []
  seed_start = seed_start.copy()

  def shift_array(array, nb_pos=1, default_value="NaN", fill=True):
    indexes = list(np.arange(nb_pos))
    new_arr = []
    for index, element in enumerate(array):
      if(index in indexes):
        pass
      else:
        new_arr.append(element)
    if(fill is True):
      while(len(new_arr) < len(array)):
        new_arr.append(default_value)
    return new_arr

  if(len(seed_start.shape) == 3):
    series.append(seed_start[0].reshape(1, -1)[0])
    #Hese is for recurrent newtorks
    for _ in range(steps):
      res = model.predict(seed_start)[0][0]
      sub_arr = seed_start[0].reshape(1, -1)[0]
      predictions.append([res])
      new_arr = shift_array(sub_arr)
      new_arr[len(new_arr) - 1] = res
      new_arr = np.array(new_arr)
      series.append(new_arr)
      new_arr = np.expand_dims(new_arr, axis=0)
      new_arr = np.expand_dims(new_arr, axis=2)
      seed_start = new_arr
  elif(len(seed_start.shape) == 2):
    #Here is for multilayer perceptron networks
    for i in range(steps):
      if(lib=="keras"):
        res = model.predict(seed_start)[0][0]
      elif(lib=="sklearn"):
        res = model.predict(seed_start)[0]
      else:
        print("lib not managed")
        return
      sub_arr = seed_start[0]
      predictions.append([res])
      new_arr = shift_array(sub_arr)
      new_arr[len(new_arr) - 1] = res
      new_arr = np.array(new_arr)
      series.append(new_arr)
      new_arr = np.expand_dims(new_arr, axis=0)
      seed_start = new_arr
  else:
    print("Dimension not managed")

  predictions = np.array(predictions)
  series = np.array(series)
  return predictions, series
```

An example of this function is given:

`seed=[[1, 2, 3]] ==> prediction=[4]
new_seed=[[2, 3, 4]] ==> prediction=[5]`

And so on...

The problem is that the predictions converged to a unique value:

[Here is the trend with forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX1AU.png)

Any idea why ?
Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: Have you considered altering the structure of your model? In general, multilayer perceptrons with densely connected layers are not good at time series analysis. Instead, you might want to look into RNNs using LSTM layers. IMHO the problem with the current network might be that it is making predictions based on faulty predictions made on the previous window.

Comment: Yes i tried many models. MLP, LSTM, GRU, Bidirectional GRU, All the models give the same problem. If we can find the problem, i can extend the solution on the other models.